# POST request doesn't accept a specific formatation of JSON, even though it's the same

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I'm trying to make a POST request to my API with the following Request Bodies:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "source": "A",
            "target": "B",
            "distance": 10
        },
        {
            "source": "A",
            "target": "C",
            "distance": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{​
  "data": [
    {​
      "source": "A", "target": "B", "distance": 6
    }​,
    {​
      "source": "A", "target": "E", "distance": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

The first one works, but the second one doesn't, and returns the following error:

```
"message": "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('​' (code 8203 / 0x200b)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('​' (code 8203 / 0x200b)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 5]"
```

That's my Controller's POST function:

```
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Graph> saveGraph(@RequestBody Graph graph){
        System.out.println(graph);
        Graph obj = graphService.saveGraph(graph);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(obj);
    }
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`0x200b`](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x200B/index.html) is the Unicode value for a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), which it seems like the Jackson JSON parser is not able to handle. Zero-width spaces aren't usually visible in most editors by default, which results in confusing situations like the one you've encountered.

Your text or code editor might have a setting to show hidden characters; I pasted both of your snippets into Sublime Text, and it showed me the hidden characters that are causing the problem:

[image: screenshot of the code in the previous post, showing multiple zero-width characters in the second JSON sample]

Removing the four zero-width characters present in the second JSON sample should resolve the error, either manually or by running the JSON sample through a regex to strip out the `0x200b` values before parsing it with Jackson.

Comment: Thank you! I would've wasted hours solving it by myself. I wonder if there's any possibility to make Jackson handle zero-width space characters.

Comment: Which text editor were you using?

Comment: The text editor in the above screenshot is [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/).